# Batch Script to compare data

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Every day in my team a group of people extract a report from a portal and name it like `ABC_23MAY2018.txt`,`XYZ_23MAY2018.txt` and save it in a directory.

But because it is a manual process people do mistake like they extract the report of `22MAY2018` (giving the wrong date on the portal input) and name it `ABC_23MAY2018.txt` etc.
This has caused of lots of issues as the file is used for reports purposes. I was thinking to create a batch script which will extract the date from the file name -`23MAY2018` and compare it with the date which will be extracted in another file date.txt. I have figured out to extract the date from file name :

```
set Filedate=ABC*.csv
 for /f %%A in ('dir /b %Filedate%') do (
  set filename=%%~A
  set fileCSV=!filename:~9,10!
  echo !filename:~9,10!
)
```

But how to compare it with the date in the file. for example, after extracting the date from filename its need to be compared it with the data.txt data which have value like :

```
ABC,23MAY2018                                                                              
XYZ,23MAY2018
```

so the date extracted from `ABC_23MAY2018.txt` need to be compared with the first line and the second column have the date. If they are equal move the file in another directory.

How do I achieve it? Hope I explained my problem well.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a batch file? Pretty much any other programming language would make this easier.

Comment: true..i have already built some validation in bach script...so wanted to do the same for this ...but other scripting languages suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'd use.

- a normal for to iterate the files `%%A`
- a for /f to split the name without extension at the `_` into `%%B` and `%%C`
- use findstr to check if `"Name,Date"` are present in date.txt.
- if found move the file

Technically the two for, the findstr and move could be on one line,
but that's more difficult to follow.

---

```
@Echo off
set "Filedate=ABC*.csv"
set "Destfolder=X:\where\ever"
for %%A in (%Filedate%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%B in ("%%~nA") Do (
        findstr /IBELC:"%%B,%%C" date.txt 2>&1>NUL && Move "%%A" "%DestFolder%"
    )
)
```

Comment: Hey Thx ..this works..can u please explain this part 2>&1>NUL

Comment: if findstr would have a find it would echo it via normal output stream (1), possible error message to the error stream( 2). Both streams are redirected to nul with that command first `2>&1` is merged with normal output, the `>Nul`. We don't need the output just the conditional execution on success `&&` of the next command.